# Selenium python how to close a pop up window?

Tags: python, selenium

Scenario:

- Click on Sign on link in the top navigation.
- This opens a an overlay form (pop up)
- I fill in email id and select radio button (new customer)
- Click Submit
- A new overlay form (pop up opens)
- I Enter all information (first,last name etc) and click Submit
- Overlay (pop up form) opens displaying a Thank you message.

Problem:- I want to click 'X' on top right of this pop up to close it.

***Have tried the following***
Xpath :

```
browser.find_elements_by_xpath('html/body/div[7]/div[1]/a/span').click()
```

***This gives error***:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\Off5th_Registration", line 25, in <module>
browser.find_elements_by_xpath('html/body/div[7]/div[1]/a/span').click()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'
```

***Tried by class name***:

```
browser.find_element_by_class_name('ui-dialog-titlebar-close ui-corner-all').click()
```

***This gives error***:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\Off5th_Registration", line 25, in <module>
browser.find_element_by_class_name('ui-dialog-titlebar-close ui-corner-all').click()
File "C:\Python27\lib\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 341, in find_element_by_class_name
return self.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value=name)
File "C:\Python27\lib\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 681, in find_element
{'using': by, 'value': value})['value']
```

Please help!!

Comment: Adding the HTML from the page:-div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix">
<span id="ui-dialog-title-2" class="ui-dialog-title"> </span>
<a class="ui-dialog-titlebar-close ui-corner-all" href="#" role="button">

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are using `find_elements_by_xpath` and this is returning you a list of elements, you should use `find_element_by_xpath` (note the non plural).

Secondly, i am not sure if your xpath is correct, although I am not sure, but i kind of remember from some place that you have to use full xpath (starting with // or /). So in your case that would be `'//html/body/div[7]/div[1]/a/span'`

Thirdly, compound class names are not supported, in webdriver context this means that you can not select by_class_name if your class name has a whitespace in it.

Anyway, try following:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@class=\"ui-dialog-titlebar-close ui-corner-all\"]').click()
```

---

EDIT to answer your comment:
perhaps you are getting there too fast? Try:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPath, '//a[@class=\"ui-dialog-titlebar-close ui-corner-all\"]')))
```

[Check here.](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions)

Comment: Thanks Erki. Still getting an error. Looks like it is not able to recognize it. saksoff5th.com is the site where i am trying this out. Please see the error below.Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Off5th_Registration", line 26, in <module>
    browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='dwfrm_login_username_d0wweltullmw']").click()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 221, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)