# How to avoid bot detection in Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape [this](https://www.zonaprop.com.ar/inmuebles-venta-rosario.html) website with the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

driver_path = '/Users/francopiccolo/Utils/chromedriver97'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path, chrome_options=options)

url = 'https://www.zonaprop.com.ar/inmuebles-venta-rosario.html'
driver.get(url)
```

The problem is it somehow detects a bot and throws an error.

[image]

Ideas?

Comment: Have you tried the solutions here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27270357/closing-a-generic-pop-up-in-selenium

Comment: I couldn't find the X button in the DOM to be able to close the popover.

Comment: You can get rid of it with options it seems to know it's a bot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
```

Try these to remove the detection of the bot.

Comment: these parameters helped over a year ago, but since then they help less and less

Comment: Try using user-agents, or just switch to undectable_chromedriver.